# How to define and use the ${project.basedir} using maven?

Tags: java, maven, path

I am trying to better understand how to resolve relative paths in maven. I have seen here ["Resolving Relative Paths."](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/common-bugs.html#resolving-relative-paths) that is a good practice to use the `project.getBasedir()` to get paths.
Initially I thought I did not have to set, so I created a maven project created a `TestClass.java` and tested the following:

In TestClass.java

```
System.out.println(project.getBaseDir());
System.out.println(project.getBaseDir()+"/folder1/folder2");
```

This generated me the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'project'.

1. So I thought I must modify my pom, but how to modify my pom?
2. Also, what is the best practice to concatenate paths in maven how could one improve this `project.getBaseDir()+"/folder1/folder2"`?

Below is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.moga</groupId>
  <artifactId>capacityplan</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>capacityplan</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source> -->
    <!-- <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target> -->
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<!--    TODO:Remove Junit4-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--        Start as per Junit5 Doc https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--        End -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.moga</groupId>
      <artifactId>genetic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
<!--    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>-->
<!--    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>-->
<!--    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>-->
<!--    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>-->

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- Define Main class, see https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-main-method -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.moga</groupId>
          <artifactId>capacityplan</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.moga.planning.nsga2.RunCapacityPlanning</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <!--        As per Junit5 Doc https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure-->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!--        End Junit5-->

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That article talks about resolving paths and variables in a maven plugin. Are you developing a maven plugin?

Comment: Hello @aksappy I am actually developing a dependency, would you recommend another link in that case?

Comment: Does that "dependency" work as a maven plugin? Or is that a java library that needs the ${project.basedir} somehow?

Comment: That is exactly a java library that expect to use the project.basedir to manage absolute paths for output reports.